# How to set request parameters when you clicking on submit?

Tags: javascript, html

I have My request parameters in the URL of current page. When I click on submit in the same page, parameters lost got lost in the new request. How to retain the request parameters even after submitting the form?

Answer (score 2):

You can read the query params from the url and add them as a hidden fields into the form you are submitting. This will send the query string params along with the form.

Answer (score 1):

1. Send the request parameters as form's GET params
2. Have the server set the  parameters in a  cookie so it is available in every page.
3. Put it in browser's local storage.

Answer (score 1):

If submitting the form via POST, you can include request parameters in the form's `action` attribute, eg

```
<form method="post" action="action?id=123&foo=bar">
<input type="text" name="baz">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Phil. I have done as you suggested. Now My app works fine.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is state management. It can be done in several ways

1. HttpSession
2. Cookies
3. Hidden fields
4. URL rewriting.

Hidden fields is an easy way to do it; although the HTML can get more lengthy. I personally prefer HttpSession.